# Updating through Terminal

Tags: apt

I entered `sudo apt-get update` in Terminal and got the following output

[image]

What to do now?

Comment: Please use the search function to determine if a question has been asked already before asking a new question. The vast majority of the results popping out when searching "malformed" are in fact the same exact question.

Comment: @Kos I went through the suggested questions but I was unable to understand and I don't have enough reputation to comment there so I asked it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute

```
sudo sed -i '/playonlinux/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

to remove the wrong entry in `sources.list` and add the repository:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: If you get a duplicate error, give me a comment.

Comment: sudo sed -i '/playonlinux/d' /etc/apt/sources.list did nothing and then I entered the second command which worked then I entered sudo sed -i '/playonlinux/d' /etc/apt/sources.list,which is working.

Comment: The first command removes the wrong entry. There is no output in the terminal.